# Docker via Engine API: how to run command during container build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-engine

In Docherfile I can write like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN mkdir /test
```

But I can't find how to do the same when creating a container via Engine API. Not the `CMD`, that runs upon container start, but `RUN`, to provision creating container. Is this possible?

Comment: Dockerfile is used to build image, not for container creation.

Comment: @Yuankun thanx, figured out that I can generate a dockerfile and build an image via api